# while printing array element in shell schript show an error. I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Tags: arrays, shell, ubuntu

```
array=("dev" "pratap" "singh")
echo $ {array[0]}
```

When run, I get:

```
dev_ps@DPS:~/Desktop/DD/Shell_Script$ sh ./dev.sh ./dev.sh: 17:
./dev.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: Your error is on the assignment line, not the printing line.  You should be able to see that if you use `sh -x ./dev.sh`.  Which shell are you using? Note that `/bin/sh` may be a link to a shell other than Bash, and may not support arrays.

Answer (score 0):

To print the `0th` index from a bash array you can use

```
echo ${array[0]}
```

But the error

> dev_ps@DPS:~/Desktop/DD/Shell_Script$ sh ./dev.sh ./dev.sh: 17:
>   ./dev.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

is likely coming from your script itself, check the syntax near line 17 and any opening and closing blocks in that location.

Comment: any other way to print individual element of array ?

Comment: @DevendraPratapSingh No. The only way is to do it correctly. Show us the first twenty lines and we'll point out the error.

Comment: as per comments above, can you tell us what shell you are using?

Comment: @the_velour_fog currently i'm using bash shell

Comment: @Jens i deleted all the above line and only run these lines                  array=("dev" "pratap" "singh")
echo ${array[0]}          now i'm getting the error in line 1

Comment: In this case, I don't think your script is executed by bash, because the assignment is valid on bash. How did you verify, that this was run by bash? When you invoke the same shell as interactive shell, and enter the command there, do you get this error message too? BTW, verify that you don't have any hidden (unprintable) characters in your script, for example by looking at it with a hex editor, or by using `od -cx`.

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL` report? It looks like you are *not* using bash.

Comment: @Jens /bin/bash                           the problem is resolve .now i'm using bash instead of sh .

Answer (score 0):

You are using sh, which is dash in Ubuntu and does not support array variables.
Try using bash instead of sh.

Comment: Thanx @Juergen now the code is running perfectly with .bash file

Comment: So you should mark this answer as the correct one :-)